# Refactor menu item for VB.NET projects in VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, refactoring

Is there any way to use the VS2008 built-in Refactoring functionality on VB.NET projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe native refactoring is for C# only. However there is Refactor! which is free.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb693327.aspx

If you register you get some more free refactoring.

Comment: I use Refactor! all the time...admittedly mostly just for creating properties from private variables, but that in itself is worth having.